# ((ActivityName) getActivity()).FragmentName.methodInFragment(); - what is (ActivityName) doing and how does it work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, casting, android-dialogfragment

I have three items here: a base activity called `ActivityName`, a fragment that is called from that activity called `FragmentName`, and a `dialogFragment` that is called from the fragment.

I wanted to call a method from the dialog that resides in the fragment. I did this using the following:

```
((ActivityName) getActivity()).fragmentName.methodInFragment();
```

I had been trying a few different solutions and finally hit upon this one. I understand what's happening, but I don't understand what `(ActivityName)` is doing. My guess is that it's casting `getActivity` to the actual activity type so I can call things from it (like the instance of the fragment I have declared in it). Is that what's happening or am I way off?

Is this the same type of thing that's use when I am accessing a `TextView` I've defined in XML. e.g. `TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thetextview);`?

Comment: You are casting the returned Activity to an ActivityName, which is a sub-class (extended class, derived class, etc.) of Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called cast. `getActivity()` returns an Activity object, and with `((ActivityName)getActivity())` you are specifying that `getActivity()` is actually an object of the class `ActivityName`. Casting to the specific type allows you to access the member and methods (`public`) that are not part of the super class. If you define a wrong cast, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

> Is this the same type of thing that's use when I am accessing a
>   TextView I've defined in XML. e.g. TextView myTextView = (TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.thetextview);?

yes it is. `findViewById` returns a `View`, and you tell that the `View` is actually a `TextView`. If instead of a `TextView`, `R.id.thetextview`, was the id of an `ImageButton`, casting it to `TextView` would have lead to a `ClassCastException`